# How can I output individual letters of a string? In my assignment, I have to get the W out of the word "Wetter"

Tags: java, arrays, string, substring

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
String satz = "Heute ist wunderbares Wetter, fahren wir doch zum Strand";

        System.out.println(satz);
        System.out.print(satz.substring(22));

    }
}
```

I tried different things, but i have always errors. i am a beginner with Java, and i try to understand strings. I tried to understand them in ANSI C, but i have no clue :D

Comment: you'll need to be more specific. Is it always the W from Wetter? Or is it always the first char of the xth word? Or .... ?

Comment: I just needed this one letter :) but i solved it already :) thx

Comment: `Character.toString( input.codePoints().toArray()[22] )` See code run at [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/3qhppK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String is an Object which has build in methods such as the one you're using .substring(). Another which might be handy for you in this case is charAt() in combination with a loop.
You can read more about which methods String object has at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: 2 minutes after i posted this, i looked something up and found charAt() :) thx for your help :)

Comment: Actually `charAt` has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. That method **fails with most characters**. Use code point integers instead to work with individual characters.

Comment: For an example of failure, see [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/3qhppK).

Answer (score 0):

```
//Print All Charchters
for (int i=0; i<satz.length(); i++) 
{ 
System.out.println(satz.charAt(i));
}

//Get char In a specific Location (Index)
System.out.println(satz.charAt(22));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out the 23rd letter you can use substring or charAt

```
    String satz = "Heute ist wunderbares Wetter, fahren wir doch zum Strand";

    System.out.println(satz);
    System.out.println(satz.charAt(22));
    System.out.println(satz.substring(22,23))
```